# Drupal Multisite Setup Goes Wrong

Tags: drupal-8, multisite

I am unable to install drupal as multisite. Below is the following step i did:

1. Download drupal 8.3.0
2. Installed drupal in my root folder www/
3. Rename drupal8.3.0 folder to druapl1
4. Created two folders [**mysite1.com** and **mysite2.com**] in drupal1/sites
5. Copied default.settings.php from sites/default folder to my two
   newly created folders **mysite1.com** and **mysite2.com**
   respectively
6. Created file sites.php in sites/ folder and inserted following code

   ```
   $sites = array(
      'mysite1.com' => 'mysite1.com', 
      'mysite2.com' => 'mysite2.com,
   );
   ```
7. Now in hosts file i have this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 www.mysite1.com
   127.0.0.1 www.mysite2.com
   ```
8. In httpd-vhosts.conf file i created a virtual host like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
      DocumentRoot "C:/www/druapl1"
      ServerName mysite1.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Now when i load this url in my browser http://www.mysite1.com/, i see full list of all projects in my root folder instead of the installation setup.Can someone tell me which step i am doing wrong Please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to also create a copy of default.settings.php as settings.php in your 'mysite1.com' and 'mysite2.com' folders respectively for it to run install process.